# How to suppress the placeins effect of figures just for two specific sections?

Tags: floats, positioning, placeins

I used the usepackage "placeins" to force the figures to be in the section or subsection of interest. However for two specific sections, I would prefer the Figures to float (to avoid white blanks). How could I deal with this? Is is possible to suppress the placeins effect for few defined sections?

```
  \usepackage[section]{placeins}
\let\Oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\FloatBarrier\Oldsection}
\let\Oldsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\FloatBarrier\Oldsubsection}
\let\Oldsubsubsection\subsubsection
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\FloatBarrier\Oldsubsubsection}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `\Oldsection` for the sections following the images which should float.